# Exploit FOUND with clamav on Fedora 21 in Oracle's java

Tags: fedora, security, malware, jdk, clamav

I'm scanning one of my systems with Clamav like this:

```
$ clamscan -r -i --remove --max-filesize=4000M --max-scansize=4000M \
     --exclude=/proc --exclude=/sys --exclude=/dev --bytecode-timeout=190000
```

It just found a virus in my download directory:

```
/home/user/Downloads/jdk-8u31-linux-x64.tar.gz: Java.Exploit.CVE_2013_2472 FOUND
/home/user/Downloads/jdk-8u31-linux-x64.tar.gz: Removed.
```

What is the damage from this kind of malware?

I downloaded this file from the official Oracle site, so I can't understand how it could be infected. Did someone manipulate this file before it entered my system and I installed some kind of malware on my Fedora?

I removed the Java in question from my system and activated openjdk from the repository.

Information from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/javacpujun2013verbose-1899853.html):

Excerpt:

> CVE-2013-2472 Vulnerability in the Java Runtime Environment component
>   of Oracle Java SE (subcomponent: 2D). Supported versions that are
>   affected are 7 Update 21 and before, 6 Update 45 and before and 5.0
>   Update 45 and before. Easily exploitable vulnerability allows
>   successful unauthenticated network attacks via multiple protocols.
>   Successful attack of this vulnerability can result in unauthorized
>   Operating System takeover including arbitrary code execution.
>
> Note: Applies to client deployment of Java only. This vulnerability
>   can be exploited only through sandboxed Java Web Start applications
>   and sandboxed Java applets.
>
> CVSS Base Score 10.0 (Confidentiality, Integrity and Availability
>   impacts). CVSS V2 Vector: (AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:C/I:C/A:C). (legend)
>   [Advisory]

What are the procedures here, is this a Linux virus? Note "result in unauthorized Operating System takeover".

#### EDIT #1

Here are the scan results:

```
/home/user/Downloads/jdk-8u31-linux-x64.tar.gz: Java.Exploit.CVE_2013_2472 FOUND                                                        
/home/user/Downloads/jdk-8u31-linux-x64.tar.gz: Removed.
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/irc-unrealircd-backdoor.nse: Unix.Trojan.MSShellcode-21 FOUND
/usr/share/nmap/scripts/irc-unrealircd-backdoor.nse: Removed.
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 3791398
Engine version: 0.98.6
Scanned directories: 103265
Scanned files: 746031
Infected files: 2
Total errors: 18624
Data scanned: 330294.49 MB
Data read: 367850.33 MB (ratio 0.90:1)
Time: 33458.657 sec (557 m 38 s)
17 April 2015
```

ClamAV is saying that there were two infections, according to @dhag this is not the case and one is an exploit/vulnerability in Java.... I am curious as to why frequently the scan is removing scripts from the nmap directory. I suspect that that's not malware but has to do with something about the capability of the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the message `Java.Exploit.CVE_2013_2472 FOUND` means that
this installer is for a version of Java affected with the security bug
you posted the description of.

If so, it's not a virus at all, just some piece of legit-but-dangerous
software. I would say the message from ClamAV is a bit confusing, and
the action of deleting the affected file may not be the most sensible,
but that's open to debate.